# How to build a svelte project from source?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, svelte

I found an useful code on Github https://github.com/ShizukuIchi/pdf-editor, but I have only written JS and HTML before. It contains a yarn.rock and some .svelte files, so I assume this might be a svelte project. I have tried to run the index.html in the browser directly but it doesn't work. What do I need to build this code?

Comment: You have to clone the project to your computer then run yarn install and after it finish downloading the dependecies run yarn start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it cannot run from index.html straightly?

Comment: No it is not possible because it needs dependencies.

Comment: After I run "yarn start", the screen shows " Your application is ready, Local:      http://localhost:5000" but I cannot visit it via the browser. Did I miss something?

Comment: Forget to mention that I run yarn on my VPS server, I tried to access it by "http://My VPS IP: 5000" but no luck.

Comment: I have solved it, thanks a lot!